# My expr is being printed but not evaluated

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, expr

The code for the script is:

```
echo "Years:"
read age
x=`expr $age*365`
echo -e $x
```

The output when I call this script from the command line is as follows:

```
Years:
```

(say I put 20)

```
20*365
```

Why is it not evaluating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we should escape the special character `*` and keep spaces between values and operator.

Try as,

```
x=`expr $age \* 365`
```

Answer (score 2):

`expr` is archaic and largely obsolete these days.  It's also very limited and clumsy to use compared to better alternatives like:

1. bash has **integer-only** arithmetic built-in these days.

   ```
   $ age=20
   $ echo "$((age * 365))"
   7300

   $ x=$((age*365))
   $ echo "$x"
   7300
   ```
2. use `bc` for floating-point arithmetic:

   ```
   $ age=20
   $ echo "$age * 365.25" | bc
   7305.00
   ```

   Or, if you want to drop the decimal fraction:

   ```
   $ echo "scale=0; $age * 365.25/1" | bc
   7305
   ```

   The division by 1 is needed because addition, subtraction, and multiplication ignore the `scale` setting in `bc`.   This is a long-standing annoyance and is unlikely to be "fixed".
3. if you prefer RPN, you could use `dc`:

   ```
   $ age=20
   $ dc -e "$age 365.25 * p" 
   7305.00
   ```

Note: backticks are obsolete and deprecated too.  Use `$(...)` instead of backticks.  e.g.

```
x=$(echo "$age * 365.25" | bc)

x=$(dc -e "$age 365.25 * p")
```

Comment: It's not that other operators ignore `scale`, it's that for other operators, maximum scale can be determined, while for division, you have to impose an arbitrary limit and the `scale` variable is used for that. `1/3` needs an infinite number of digits after the radix for instance, so you need choose where to stop.

Comment: The practical effect of that, though, is that you're going to get a trailing .00 or whatever on the result of any operation that doesn't involve a division, no matter what you set scale to.